# Is endpoint with HTTPS not enough to avoid sniffing attacks?

Tags: rest, http, https, sniffing

My Endpoint is accompanied by HTTPS but if I post user credentials via this endpoint, how is it vulnerable to sniffing attacks? Is endpoint with HTTPS not enough or some other implementations are also required?

If I POST user credential via an REST endpoint.

Statement 1: My endpoint is HTTPS enabled.

Statement 2: The transmission channel is HTTPS encrypted.

What are the differences in these 2 statements?

I am sending post request via https enabled REST api even though the post data is visible when intercept is on.

Following image was provided by our VAPT team saying that the endpoint is not secure since they are able to intercept the traffic and retrieve the post data like username and password.

[image]

Comment: Right. Context is king. What is that screenshot from? Where is that intercept? Is that on the client or a man-in-the-middle? Did you install certificates on the client to make that intercept work? Have you read the Burp manual? Did you just run a tool having no idea how it works and then get scared when it worked?

Comment: I received this from the VAPT (Vulnerability Assessment and Penetration Testing) Team. The screenshot is from Burp Suite. But I don't know what processes they used to conduct the same.

Comment: Right. and what ***else*** did they say about that screenshot?

Comment: They said transmit the data via an encrypted channel (HTTPS) to avoid being intercepted by malicious users. That's all. Also they don't know how?

Comment: This question is now all over the place and disjointed. You have several questions in one. If your goal is to figure out what vulnerability that screenshot represents, then  ***ask the VAPT team***. If they intercepted their own traffic, then that's not a vulnerability. That screenshot needs relevance and context.

Comment: "They said transmit the data via an encrypted channel (HTTPS) " -- that makes no sense whatsoever. That screenshot is from the *client* and it is over HTTPS. It says so at the top.

Comment: Okay. Well, thanks a lot about giving me enough context to ask them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTTPS encrypts the transmission channel so that any node between the client and server cannot read the plaintext content. The traffic can still be ***sniffed***, but the sniffed data is encrypted. This is a very important distinction because if the encryption is weak or if it is cracked in the future, any saved, encrypted data might be decrypted.

---

What is the difference between:

1. My endpoint is HTTPS enabled.
2. The transmission channel is HTTPS encrypted.

It's the difference between "I know how to bake a cake" and "I am baking a cake". Just having something enabled doesn't mean it is being used or that HTTPS hasn't been bypassed or disabled somehow.

Comment: Are you saying that sending the sensitive data via POST method in https enabled REST endpoint alone not enough?

Comment: I think we have a language issue. I'm saying that the POST data has to be sent over HTTPS. Just being "enabled" is not enough. "Enabled" is about "potential", not about what is actually happening.

Comment: When intercept is on, the post data is visible even though the link have https. Don't know why?

Comment: And now we have an indication that there is a world of context that you have omitted... Do you mean Burp Suite? Where you set up an intermediate certificate to trust and the data gets re-encrypted from your proxy?